# View and plane/section of neural tube

Tags: anatomy

I have a question regarding the following image:

[image]

In my book, it states that this is a dorsal view which shows the formation of the neural tube. However, isn't this a caudal view of a transverse section? A dorsal and ventral view wouldn't apply to a transverse section right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a dorsal view to me, like your book says.

It isn't a section at all, these are embryonic structures visible from the outside.

Maybe you are being misled by the orientation of the [neuraxis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuraxis) differing among organisms? The head will develop at the anterior neuropore; the spine will develop down the middle. You are looking at what will be the back.

Here's another view from Gray's (downloaded from Wikipedia at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somite#/media/File:Gray20.png ):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The neural folding was shown from two different perspectives. The first perspective being the original image in the post and the second one being: https://i0.wp.com/veteriankey.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/c16f002-1.gif?w=960

That image is a 'sagittal section'. In that case, isn't the original image the top (cranial) view of this section?

Comment: @Stallmp It doesn't make much sense to refer to a "cranial" view when there is no cranium. Certainly neither of these is a sagittal section, though. Your second image in the comment is a transverse slice; in that image, dorsal is "up". Can you provide a citation from what book this is or at least a more complete image? You've cut off all the description and explanation.

Comment: So if you look at the original post in my message, this is apparently a dorsal view as mentioned. There is also an anterior neuropore, which is the cranial neuropore, and a posterior neuropore, which is the caudal neuropore. In that case, isn't the second image a 'sagittal' view of either the cranial or caudal neuropore?

Comment: No, the second image is not a sagittal view of anything, and it is not showing a neuropore. In (B), you see the neural folds closing in, such that in (C) it has closed and formed a neural canal. So it's from someplace in the middle of the first image. See the "somites" on each image (same thing as "primitive segments" on the one I posted)?